# How to make sqllite database call and store return value to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

I need to covert C# code to JavaScript and I've got stuck with async database calls.
I’m pretty new to JavaScript and I don’t know how to solve this problem. I know it must be done with callback function but I just don’t know how to write it. I've tried some few examples I've found on this site but without success.
If someone can help me with this please help.

I have 2 tables in project. Lets say **Table1** and **Table2**. Table1 is parent table and Table2 is child that contains items for Table1.
They are connected with id.

**Table1** (Id, userid, Col1, Col2)

**Table2** (Id, Col1, Col2, Col3)

Data is stored in SQL LITE database, I need to make a call to read that data and send it in JSON format.

I have next code.

```js
var Table1row = {};
var Table1Array = [];
var Table2row = {};
var Table2Array = [];

function GetTable1()
{ 
     try 
     {  
    db.transaction(
             function(transaction) 
             { 
                 transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE userid  = ?',
         [userid],  DataHandlerTable1, txError);
             });
     } 
     catch(e) 
     {
         console.log(e.message);
     }  
}
```

```js
function DataHandlerTable1 (tx,results)
{   
    var len = results.rows.length;    
    if(len > 0)      
    {
         for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
         {
             row = results.rows.item(i);

             Table1row ["id"] = row.id;         
             Table1row ["userid"] = row.userid;
             Table1row ["Col1"] = row.Col1;
             Table1row ["Col2"] = row.Col2;
             Table1row ["Table2Array"] = GetTable2(row.id);

            Table1Array.push(Table1row);
         }

         var jsonObject = { prod: Table1Array }

            Type = "POST";
            Url = "http://192.168.136.27:54076/Service1.svc/SaveResult";
            ContentType = "application/json";
            DataType = "json";

            $.ajax({            
                type: Type, 
                url: Url, 
                contentType: ContentType, 
                data: JSON.stringify(jsonObject),
                dataType: DataType, 
                success: function (json) {                                    
                },
                error: function (jqXHR,exception) {                     
                },
            });              
     }  
}
```

Problem is in this line:

```
Table1row ["Table2Array"] = GetTable2(row.id);
```

This does not work and i don't know how to write this other way in JavaScript.
I need to store in **Table1row ["Table2Array"]** return value of **GetTable2()** function.

```js
function GetTable2(id)
{
        db.transaction(function(transaction) {              
             transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id  = ?', [id],   function (tx, results) {                  
                 var len = results.rows.length;
                 if(len > 0)         
                 {
                     for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
                     {
                         row = results.rows.item(i);
                         Table2row ["id"] = row.id;
                         Table2row ["Col1"] = row.Col1;    
                         Table2row ["Col2"] = row.Col2;
                         Table2row ["Col3"] = row.Col3;

                         Table2Array.push(Table2row);               
                         }

                     return Table2Array;
                     }                                                                 
             });                 
     });        
}
```

Any ideas about this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are approaching the problem incorrectly, it sounds like you do not understand how to write good javascript code. I suggest you read up on it starting with the book "Javascript The Good Parts". If you are using async code, you will need to make all of your code async.

A rough idea is as follows.

```
function GetTable1(callback) {
  [...]
  transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE userid  = ?',
     [userid], function(tx, results) { DataHandlerTable1(tx, results, callback); }, txError);
  [...]
}
function DataHandlerTable1 (tx,results,callback) {
  [...]
  GetTable2(row.id, function(value) {
    Table1row ["Table2Array"] = value
  });
[...]
callback(jsonObject);
}
function GetTable2(id, callback) {
  [...]
  callback(Table2Array);
  return;
}
```

Again, it is a bad idea to assume you can port c# over to javascript without having a fundamental understanding of the javascript language.

Comment: Thanks for helping me to understand what i am doing wrong. Ive start learning javascript by converting this c# application of mine. I ll get that book you have recommended.Thank you. I appreciate it.